Destructive interference pattern perpendicular to photon's propagation direction
I'm studying the interference pattern for light. For example, the following is the interference pattern for double slit experiment:

I'm curious to know if there is an existing interference pattern for light where the dark (destructive interference) lines are perpendicular to the wave/ photon propagation. I draw the below sketch to clarify the idea:

I searched but couldn't find such pattern. Can this pattern be exist? Does it violate locality because energy can't transfer thru dark (destructive interference) area?

Would a standing wave be what you are after?

@BySymmetry thank you for your answer. But do energy transfer across the nodes incase of ideal standing waves?

No it can not exist.  In high school you learn that 2 waves cancel, but this is not physics it is only mathematics. Energy is never absorbed or destroyed in the medium, water waves seem to cancel but in reality the waves re-emerge and travel onward. Typically the energy was stored in the elasticity of the water, only when the waves crash on the beach is the energy absorbed.
For photons the medium is the EM field, 2 photons traveling out of phase together still have all the energy of the 2 photons.  If they were to meet a screen they would scatter and separate ... eventually they will get absorbed.

I do understand your point that photons can't cancel each other. But my question is for the interference pattern which is normally a lines parallel to direction of propagation (similar to 1st Fig.). My question: is there any existing interference pattern where the interference lines (constructive & destructive interference) are perpendicular to wave propagation direction. I just want to know if photon can cross these destructive interference lines to the destination.

@WaelKhatib you can search my answers on the website. You will read photons take preferred paths, Feynman path integral, photons like to travel paths that are multiples of it’s wavelength, that’s why Huygens luckily works out. Em field is everywhere, all electrons/ atoms  contribute to it, it’s forces resonate, photons are dumb as the em field guides them.
